# Comparar 2 datagridview con muchos registros de manera rápida

Tags: visual-studio, vba

estoy trabajando en un programa en visual basic que compara 2 excel subidos en dos datagridview diferentes. Cada excel tiene id de usuarios y lo que hace es poner en rojo las filas de los usuarios están en el primer excel pero que no se encuentran en el segundo.

El problema es que ya que son 2 excel con más de mil registros la comparación tarda mucho tiempo ya que lo que hago es tomar un id del primer datagridview y compararlo con cada uno de los id del segundo datagridview para ver si hay una coincidencia o no.

Este es el código que utilizo y no sé si haya un modo de mejorarlo para hacer la comparación más rápida y eficiente:

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount() - 1

        NUMSOC = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("NUMSOC").Value


        For A As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.RowCount() - 1
            NUM_SOCIO = DataGridView2.Rows(A).Cells("NUM_SOCIO").Value()

            If (NUMSOC = NUM_SOCIO) Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            End If

            If DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor <> Color.LightBlue Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If


        Next
      Next
```

Suele tardar tanto que da la sensación que el programa se cuelga lo que me tiene bastante frustrado y no encuentro modo de reducir ese tiempo. ¿Alguien que pueda ayudarme?

Comment: porque no compruebas si es diferente una de la otra y le asignas directamente rojo?

    If (NUMSOC <> NUM_SOCIO) Then
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else 
    DataGridView1.Rows(i).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue          
    End If

Y para que quieres SECORTE y SECTOR_LECTURA si no los utilizas luego?

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Es verdad! No se me había ocurrido asignarles el color rojo de esa manera. Las otras variables las utilizaba también al principio porque creí que el id podía repetirse pero no la combinación entre id+SECORTE por un lado y el id+SECTOR_LECTURA por el otro pero resulta que el id era único. Ahora mismo las saco del código ya que como dices no tienen utilidad.

Comment: Para comparar de forma rápida y eficaz, podrías meter los ID de un libro en un diccionario, y los de otro en un array. Esto te haría la comprobación casi al instante, luego ya si quieres que se pinten las celdas, le dices a la macro que por cada coincidencia las meta en un rango con `Union()` y finalmente las pintas todas de rojo a la vez

Comment: Hola amigo, perdón si la petición es muy tonta pero podías darme un ejemplo de código o lógica de lo que me sugieres? Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación por lo que todavía me pierdo un poco jaja. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @Carlos22 te he dejado una respuesta con un ejemplo, ya necesitarías adecuarlo a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que te sirva esto de ejemplo:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Comparativa()

    Dim wbOrigen As Workbook, wbComparativa As Workbook, wsOrigen As Worksheet, wsComparativa As Worksheet
    Dim C As Range, Ruta As String, Archivo As String
    Dim DictComparativa As Scripting.Dictionary 'para que esto funcione necesitas la libreria Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    With Application 'esto incrementa la velocidad haciendo que no veamos lo que se está haciendo
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'Primero damos valor a las variables de libros y hojas
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'supongamos que el código lo vas a poner en el libro que tiene más ID
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) 'supongamos que esa hoja es la primera, si no sería wb.Sheets("NombreHoja")

    'ahora el libro que compararemos
    Ruta = "C:\"
    Archivo = Dir(Ruta & "*nombre del archivo*") ' yo aquí te recomiendo poner una palabra clave
    If Archivo = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'si no encuentra el archivo se acabará la macro
    Set wbComparativa = Workbooks.Open(Ruta & Archivo, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True) 'abrimos el libro
    Set wsComparativa = wbComparativa.Sheets(1) 'suponiendo que la hoja a comparar sea la primera

    'Ahora metemos los datos del libro de comparativa en un diccionario
    'Vamos a suponer que en ambos libros estamos comparando la columna A
    Set DictComparativa = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each C In wsComparativa.Range("A2", "A" & wsComparativa.Cells(wsComparativa.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Not DictComparativa.Exists(C.Value) Then DictComparativa.Add C.Value, C.Row 'metemos todos los ID en el diccionario y obviamos duplicados
    Next C

    'Prescindimos ya del libro comparativa
    wbComparativa.Close Savechanges:=False
    Set wbComparativa = Nothing
    Set wsComparativa = Nothing

    'Finalmente comparamos
    With ws
        For Each C In .Range("A2", "A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) 'recorremos la columna A
            If Not DictComparativa.Exists(C.Value) Then C.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'si el valor no está en el diccionario, lo pintamos en rojo
        Next C
    End With

    With Application 'devolvemos todo a su estado normal
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ejemplo, amigo. Quedo muy agradecido y marco como respuesta aceptada